# Number of ways to label a die

Tags: combinatorics

I think I am on the right track on this probability question but just wanted to get it checked.

“If you have a regular die and you wipe the numbers off the sides of the die. How many different unique ways can you put the numbers (1-6) on the die? (So that if you turn the die, there is no same combination)”

I was thinking that this would simply be $6!$ (factorial). Figured that one side has $6$ numbers that could be picked. Once that is done, the next side only has $5$ numbers. Next $4$, then $3$ etc.

Comment: Do you want all different numbers on there, or can I write a $6$ on all sides? Also, the $6!$ doesn't take turning the die into account.

Comment: I don't think that is this easy. I think there are other manipulations that you did not consider yet

Comment: I’m assuming that they’d have to be different numbers on all sides.

Comment: Put 6 on the top face. Then five choices for number on bottom face. Now put smallest remaining number on nearest vertical face. That leaves three numbers which can be placed in six ways. So 30.

Comment: @almagest  You should write up your comment as an answer.

Comment: Is the question equivalent to coloring the cube's faces with six colors, or does the way you write the numbers matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that there are $24$ ways of turning the die. This is because if you consider one particular face of the die, there are exactly $4$ ways of turning it so that this face is always in the same place. Then do the same for the other faces, and get $4 \times 6 = 24$.

$6!$ is the number of ways to number the die but this also counts the $24$ possible turns of the die. So the answer is $\frac{6!}{24}=30$.

Comment: This answer mostly makes sense to me, particularly the 1st part. However, I’m a bit confused as to why we take 6! and divide by 24.

Comment: $6!$ is the number of ways to number the die, but when we include all the ways we can turn the die. For instance, consider a certain numbering. Then, turn the die any way you want. These two combinations, which we consider to be identical, are counted separately when we take $6!$. So, basically, every combination that we'd like to count is counted 24 times if we do the reasoning that you described in your question. That is why we divide by 24.

Answer (score 2):

Write the number $1$ on one of the faces. You then have a choice of $5$ numbers to go on the opposite face.

For each such choice, the remaining $4$ numbers can be arranged in $\frac{4!}{4}=6$ ways, and hence the total is $5\times 6=30$

Answer (score 1):

There is  famous recreational toy connected with this question: [Mac Mahon's cubes](http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/macmahon.htm).

Assume the die is standing on the face colored $6$. There are $5$ choices for the top face. The remaining $4$ colors can be paired off in $3$ ways to ornate opposite vertical faces, and  the resulting pairs can be arranged in $2$ mirror equivalent ways on these faces. Makes $5\cdot3\cdot2=30$ colorings.